# CameraPreview takePicture() returns nothing

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have been trying to update an old app that had an old version of the camera-preview plugin, which still had the `setOnPictureTakenHandler` method that allowed me to return the url of the image.

The newer version of the plugin uses the `takePicture()` method in which I can define a function that will be called onSuccess and I defined that function to return the URL of the image taken. But I can't get that URL outside of the `onSuccess` function!

I have just been moving to typescript so I guess it's some sort of mistake managing variables. I am using a provider for the cameraPreview and I have created an envelope for the `takePicture()` method of the plugin. That envelope should return the URL to the controller in which I have injected the provider.

Here is the provider's envelope code:

```
url:string;
takePictures2() :string {    
    this.cameraPreview.takePicture(function(imgData){
        this.url = "data:image/jpeg;base64" + imgData;
    }).then();    
    return this.url;
};
```

Here is the controller code:

```
takePictures() {
    let url : string = this.cameraPreview.takePictures2();
    console.log(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested the code below, but I would:

1) [Promisify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) `takePicture2`. It wraps the `takePicture` method of the plugin and resolves the url when done:

```
takePictures2(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.cameraPreview.takePicture(function(imgData) {
            resolve("data:image/jpeg;base64" + imgData);
        });
    };
};
```

2) make `takePictures` wait for takePictures2 to resolve:

```
takePictures() {
    let url : string;
    this.cameraPreview.takePictures2().then(url => {
        this.url = url;
        console.log(url);
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works just fine for what I need!